# Can I continue shooting when film camera counter was reset to 1 after opening film door?

Tags: olympus, film-cameras

First off sorry for the bad terminology but I'm a newbie and would really appreciate some help - I've bought my first film camera, it is an Olympus MJU zoom 70 from an as-is sale and everything seemed to be working fine.

I took 9 shots with it already but the lens got stuck while I was playing with the zoom functions. I couldn't turn the camera off, and I read online that I should open the film door to reset the whole camera. I pressed the release door button (while holding the door down so the door wouldn't open and films inside wouldn't get exposed to light), and it managed to "unstick" my camera lens, but I didn't know that it would reset the film counter back to 1.

I honestly don't know how a film camera works, so questions below:

1. Can the films inside still be used?
2. Can I continue taking photos with it as per normal?

I don't really want to get the film developed right now as there are still quite a lot of exposures left and it's quite expensive to get it developed where I live. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how many exposures you had already made?

Comment: @MichaelC they specify 9

Answer (score 6):

The counter on a film camera is just for your convenience - to help you assess how many pictures have been taken on the roll and thus, how many can still be taken. The actual frame that will be exposed on the film will depend on how much the film has mechanically advanced.

The Olympus mju-70 has auto-load feature, so quite likely it advanced the film by a couple of frames when you closed the lid. So you can keep in mind that there are about 11 frames used on the roll, in addition to what the counter shows. Indicated film capacity is not a precise number - often there are some extra frames. The mju-70 will automatically rewind the film when it cannot advance it after taking a picture.